# Guardar texto de un text() para mandar lo guardado Tkinter

Tags: python, base-de-datos, tkinter, text

tengo un pequeño problema con mi proyecto, es acerca de un registro medico usando TKinter, y tengo una ventana en la cual es para añadir al paciente, todo funciona de momento bien, pero en el apartado de síntomas, quiero que sea libre, osea, que el medico (usuario), pueda poner los síntomas que el detecte, o el texto que quiera

Adjunto una imagen para que se entienda un poco mejor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Del lado izquierdo es el metodo text(), para que el usuario escriba todo lo que quiera, pero lo que no se es como guardar eso escrito en una variable o algo similar al get, para luego mandarlo a la base de datos.

Ya intente o mismo que como si fuese un Entry, pero no me sirve.

es un proyecto que tengo que entregar pronto, de verdad apreciaría mucho la ayuda, cual sea

Comment: deberia ser exactamente igual al nombre.. que problema particular tuviste?

Comment: Cuando hago la sintaxis como el entry,
self.ecorreo=StringVarc()
self.correo=Entry(self.interfazlista,textvariable=self.ecorreo, width="23")

a la hora de hacerlo con el text(), no lo detecta y me da error

Comment: Osea asi:

sintomas=self.sintomas.get()


self.sintomass=Text(self.interfazlista, textvariable=self.sintomas, height=17,width=23).place(x="34",y="231")

Comment: Oh ya pude, econtre una forma, usando casi lo mismo, nada mas quitando el textvarible() de el text(), y en la varible para guardar el texto solo añadiendo en los parentesis de donde a donde quiero copiar el texto 
self.sintoma=self.sintomass.get(1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola suponiendo que tu Text se llame  text1 podes recoger su valor en mi_variable asi:

```
mi_variable = text1.get(1.0, 'end')
```

donde 1.0 indica la coordenada de comienzo del Text
y end hasta el final del texo

variando esos valores podes tomar solo partes del mismo pero asi carga desde el principio al final del mismo